# In Gerrit is it possible to auto-suggest reviewers based on how many reviews s.o. did in the past?

Tags: plugins, gerrit, review

In a Gerrit driven workflow we face the problem that the same few people have to do all the reviews just because we got used to picking them or they are the 'oldest' colleagues with the most changes (which makes the reviewers-by-blame plugin problematic for us).

I'd like to prefer reviewers (from a given list) who don't do reviews very often (maybe because they're new or relatively unknown to others).
This approach hopefully would spread the knowledge about the code base and balance the load among colleagues.

Is this possible with Gerrit? Maybe there's a plugin already? Something generic maybe?

Comment: Side point (way off to the side). Assigning people to review who are unfamiliar with the code might provide a false sense of security when they approve, and you miss out on some expert advice/feedback. Perhaps a better way to achieve knowledge transfer would be a group code review where the developers explain what they did, and why, in a short review session (15 minutes or less). That being said, if most of your developers *could* do the reviews as well as the regulars, then this comment obviously doesn't apply to you.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, and we won't blindly assign newcomers to critical code reviews of course. The plan is to do some experiments, maybe with groups of three or in sessions as you suggested but we also want to get seldom-reviewers used to the process without having to tell them to but rather with a self-regulating process.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Gerrit owners plugin](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/owners/). In particular, owner autoassign allows you to automatically set reviewers depending on [different matching rules](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/owners/+/refs/heads/master/owners-autoassign/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md#configuration).

The list with the reviewers you would like to automatically add will have to go in the `OWNERS` file as specified by the configuration previously linked.

Bear in mind the list is static and you will have to update it.